# php iterating dom links progressively slower

Tags: php, for-loop, dom, foreach

Ok, here's my problem.  I have a HTML that has almost 180,000 links in it.  I'm creating a dom in order to extract those links and then, add them to an array for later processing.

The problem I'm having is, and this is something I've done a bit of research on, the foreach gets progressively slower with each iteration. I've looked at comparisons of for vs foreach and from what I'm reading this is the fastest method.  In my case, it's still terminally slow.

Here's a log of it's progress on the first 30,000 links.  The first 5,000 are done in about a second.  The last 1,000, 10 seconds.  By the time it hits say 80,000 it's taking 30 seconds to do 1,000.

```
2021-07-12 17:07:01 : 30000 links
2021-07-12 17:06:51 : 29000 links
2021-07-12 17:06:42 : 28000 links
2021-07-12 17:06:34 : 27000 links
2021-07-12 17:06:26 : 26000 links
2021-07-12 17:06:18 : 25000 links
2021-07-12 17:06:11 : 24000 links
2021-07-12 17:06:02 : 23000 links
2021-07-12 17:05:48 : 22000 links
2021-07-12 17:05:35 : 21000 links
2021-07-12 17:05:26 : 20000 links
2021-07-12 17:05:18 : 19000 links
2021-07-12 17:05:12 : 18000 links
2021-07-12 17:05:05 : 17000 links
2021-07-12 17:04:59 : 16000 links
2021-07-12 17:04:55 : 15000 links
2021-07-12 17:04:52 : 14000 links
2021-07-12 17:04:50 : 13000 links
2021-07-12 17:04:47 : 12000 links
2021-07-12 17:04:45 : 11000 links
2021-07-12 17:04:43 : 10000 links
2021-07-12 17:04:41 : 9000 links
2021-07-12 17:04:40 : 8000 links
2021-07-12 17:04:38 : 7000 links
2021-07-12 17:04:38 : 6000 links
2021-07-12 17:04:37 : 5000 links
2021-07-12 17:04:36 : 4000 links
2021-07-12 17:04:36 : 3000 links
2021-07-12 17:04:36 : 2000 links
2021-07-12 17:04:36 : 1000 links
```

I've done set_time_limit(1000) and still haven't gotten through all of them before the timer runs out.

Here's the code that I have that appears to be working the fastest.  I've also tried doing a do/while loop and unsetting the first element of the object.  That was a bad idea.

Please tell me there's a way to have PHP do the last 1000 just as fast as it does the first 1000.

```
        $content = $dom->getElementsByTagname('a');
        $count = 0;
        $this->write_log(count($content) . " total links");
        
        foreach ($content as $item) {
            $count++;
            if ($count % 1000 == 0) {
                $this->write_log($count . " links");
            }
            $item = rtrim($item->getAttribute('href'), '/');
            if (filter_var($item, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)) {
                $this->DocInfo->links[] = $item;
            }
        }
```

Thanks

*edit Log with cOle2's code:

```
2021-07-12 18:35:14 : 26000 links
2021-07-12 18:35:03 : 25000 links
2021-07-12 18:34:53 : 24000 links
2021-07-12 18:34:41 : 23000 links
2021-07-12 18:34:29 : 22000 links
2021-07-12 18:34:21 : 21000 links
2021-07-12 18:34:14 : 20000 links
2021-07-12 18:34:05 : 19000 links
2021-07-12 18:33:56 : 18000 links
2021-07-12 18:33:47 : 17000 links
2021-07-12 18:33:39 : 16000 links
2021-07-12 18:33:34 : 15000 links
2021-07-12 18:33:31 : 14000 links
2021-07-12 18:33:25 : 13000 links
2021-07-12 18:33:22 : 12000 links
2021-07-12 18:33:18 : 11000 links
2021-07-12 18:33:16 : 10000 links
2021-07-12 18:33:14 : 9000 links
2021-07-12 18:33:12 : 8000 links
2021-07-12 18:33:11 : 7000 links
2021-07-12 18:33:11 : 6000 links
2021-07-12 18:33:10 : 5000 links
2021-07-12 18:33:10 : 4000 links
2021-07-12 18:33:10 : 3000 links
2021-07-12 18:33:10 : 2000 links
2021-07-12 18:33:09 : 1000 links
```

Comment: If you remove the logging part, is it faster?

Comment: I've played with that a bit as it does write the log to a MySQL table.  But even if I set the modulo to 10,000 it's still keeps getting slower and slower.  I empty the table before each run and the log function is just a simple insert.

Comment: Try just iterating, don't do any work although you can still log, see if that is any faster

Comment: Yea, now I am confused.  I disabled the work as suggested. Progressively slower.  I disabled the logging and instead just echoed the date and count. Still progressively slower.  This is part of a wp plugin so I'm not sure if wp would be slowing down this output.  I'm using a JS to display the log.  Gonna chop that out and see if it has an effect.  Thanks!

Comment: Disabled my js and just echoed the time and date, still progressively slower.

Comment: If you're on a server under memory pressure it's possible that after the first handful of records fill up the memory pages that PHP had available when it started, and then you're contending with the OS cramming things into swap to make more space. That said, that's just an educated guess, and there's little information in your post that indicates a definitive cause.

Comment: One potential alternative is: Don't make step one "cram everything into a giant array" and then step two "iterate over the giant array". If possible, get one piece of information, do the thing with it, discard it, and move onto the next.

Comment: Yes, it's on a shared host but, there's supposedly 2gb ram available and according to cpanel this is only using a fraction of that.  I know the actual HTML is <30mb.  Step 2 includes adding the links to a table.  If I do that while iterating over each one it's going to make it even slower compared to combining the data from say 10 inserts into 1 bigger query.  180,000 queries vs 18,000.  And I know there's no definitive cause which is why I'm here, trying to figure it out.   Either way, why would iterating over an object that I assume is already in memory cause this if I'm doing no processing?

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with large arrays that have a fixed size you can use [SplFixedArray](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splfixedarray.php) as it can be a bit faster than standard arrays. I think you should debug a bit into where the time is going, however something like the following may be worth trying:

```
$content = $dom->getElementsByTagname('a');
$count = 0;
$this->write_log(count($content) . " total links");

$splArray = new SplFixedArray(count($content)); //create splfixed array

foreach ($content as $idx=>$item) { //track the index
    $count++;
    if ($count % 1000 == 0) {
        $this->write_log($count . " links");
    }
    $item = rtrim($item->getAttribute('href'), '/');
    if (filter_var($item, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL)) {
        $splArray[$idx] = $item; //assign item to fixed array position
    }
}

$this->DocInfo->links = $splArray->toArray(); //convert to a standard array
```

Comment: Just added the output log to the op where I substituted your code for what I had.  Seems a bit slower.  Didn't even make it to 30,000 links.

Comment: SplFixedArray _used_ to be faster in _some_ cases. After recent optimizations to arrays it's now usually a performance _penalty_.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  It's in objects themselves and the complexity of dom.  I came to this conclusion after some testing.  Below is the test code I used and you can run it here and see for your self: https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0a05fb4ad46a942a9d72cae51af819665904a037

**What I discovered:**

Objects are slower than arrays when it comes to iterating through large ones.  With a single dimension array and object, the difference wasn't that significant but it was apparent objects were slower.  Where objects really take a nose dive is when you start adding key=>value pairs. Arrays however, with key=>value pairs, don't seem to suffer any significant speed loss compared to a single dimension array.

In my OP, I was using

```
$content = $dom->getElementsByTagname('a');
```

which created an object.  But it wasn't just an object of links.  I'm not familiar with the internals of dom but it appears it was a pretty complex object and iterating over it consumed massive amounts of time.

I confirmed this by creating an array of links using regex instead of dom:

```
preg_match_all("/<a\s[^>]*href\s*=\s*([\"\']??)([^\"\' >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU", $html, $content);
```

Because regex baffles me and I don't quite understand what this is doing, this created a multi-dimensional array which was a lot more than I need but it did the job for testing purposes. I substituted $content in my original code for $content[2]  from the array and changed the rtrim to remove the ->getAttribute. I was able to iterate over the $content[2] and process all 180,000 links in about 5 seconds and that included writing logs to MySQL.

**Test Code that enlightened me:**

In this test code I create an array of hashes just to give it substance and then copy that to an object.  I then iterate over both and compare the times. I then create a key->value pair array of hashes and copy that to an object.  I iterate over both and compare times.

I also attempted this with the key=>value pairs like this:

```
foreach ($hashes as $key=>&$value) {
```

which ended up slowing down the multi-dimensional array to the point that it was even slower than the object version even though no changes to the value were made.

```php
<?php
$hashes = array();
for ($x=0;$x<150000;$x++) {
    $hashes[] = md5(rand(1,1000));
}

function iterate($hashes) {
    $count = 0;
    $time_start = microtime(true);
    foreach ($hashes as $hash) {
        $count++;
        if ($count % 1000 == 0) {
            $time_end = microtime(true);
            $time = $time_end - $time_start;
            echo $count.' : '.$time.' : '."\n";
        }
    }    
}

$ohashes = (object)$hashes;
iterate($ohashes);
echo 'Done with single object'."\n";
echo "\n";
iterate($hashes);
echo 'Done with single array'."\n";
echo "\n";
echo "\n";
unset($hashes);
unset($ohashes);

$hashes = array();
for ($x=0;$x<150000;$x++) {
    $kv = md5($x);
    $hashes[$kv] = $kv;
}

function iterate2($hashes) {
    $count = 0;
    $time_start = microtime(true);
    foreach ($hashes as $key=>$value) {
        $count++;
        if ($count % 1000 == 0) {
            $time_end = microtime(true);
            $time = $time_end - $time_start;
            echo $count.' : '.$time.' : '."\n";
        }
    }    
}

$ohashes = (object)$hashes;
iterate2($ohashes);
echo 'Done with multi object'."\n";
echo "\n";
iterate2($hashes);
echo 'Done with multi array'."\n";
```

**What I take from this:**

So, if my test code is accurate and I read it's results correctly, arrays are faster than objects when it comes to iterating.  The more complex the object, the slower it's going to be in relation to a comparable array.